# Spring + Hibernate SQL entity name not resolved

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

In Hibernate SQL, Class Name(Entity) not recognised.Compile time error, I have done following

**Entity Class**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

     //Getter And Setter
```

**Dao Class**

```
import com.springapp.model.UserEntity;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
@Repository
public class UserDaoServiceImpl implements UserDaoService{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addUser(UserEntity user) {
         this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserEntity> findAllUser() {
       return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from UserEntity").list();
    }
}
```

**Hibernate Config File**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.springapp.model.UserEntity" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Compile time error says "**Can't resolve symbol UserEntity**"...What is the problem?

Comment: Show yours hibernate xml config file

Comment: I have edited...please check

Comment: share full stack trace

Comment: @Gautam, no problem in import (Check Updated Source)

Answer (score 0):

Add default constructor and  Serializable interface to the entity bean and check now...

Comment: no same result after adding default constructor and implementing Serializable

Answer (score 0):

you cannot create a table with name `user` it is a reserved key word. try changing it to something like`user-entity` it should work.

Comment: in your entity class, the `@table` annotation still says the `value` as `user` did you change that as well?

Comment: please update your question and add the context files as well